# A body part weird looking

Tags: word, knowledge

> Two consonants joined
>
> Two flags combined
>
> A body part weird looking
>
> An old European King

Hint

> Consonants from an old European alphabet. A nine letter word.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is:

> **BLUETOOTH**

*Two consonants joined*

> The logo for the wireless technology [Bluetooth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth) is:
>  [image]
>
>  This is a [combination](http://www.thewestologist.com/symbols/bluetooth-symbol-origin-and-meaning) of the consonants "H" and "B" written in Viking runes:
>  [image]

*Two flags combined*

> The logo might also be seen to resemble two flags on poles which have been crossed over diagonally...

*A body part weird looking*

> A **blue tooth** is a body part which definitely doesn't look quite right!

*An old European King*

> [**Harald "Bluetooth" Gormsson**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harald_Bluetooth) was King of Denmark in the 10th century. In fact, the 'H' and 'B' which make up the logo are taken from his initials (and his being Danish explains the use of Danish Viking runes)!

Comment: amazingly fast @Stiv. And here I thought more hints will be needed!

Comment: Thanks @DEEM - I actually (somehow) had it from just the third and fourth lines, realised the significance of the first and second lines, then the hint only corroborated by answer! I think I actually [saw it referenced on *QI* once](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sp7T-j2Dczw) and it must have stayed at the back of my mind! :)